# Gridsome build fails when used with vue2-leaflet plugin

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, gridsome

When running `gridsome build` I get `window is not defined`. Anyone has an example of **making vue2-leaflet** work with the client only option for gridsome?

Comment: Did you get this working? If not, please post your leaflet import code.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your component inside template with `<ClientOnly>` tag, more info in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60197926/12584011)

Comment: Thanks [@Hermesis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12584011/hermesis), wrapping the template with `<ClientOnly>` was part of the solution. This is what worked for me in the end: [https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/issues/646](https://github.com/gridsome/gridsome/issues/646)

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same problem (but with other libraries) and the only solution i've found was to copy the package into `src/`. Something like :

```
cp -a node_modules/package-giving-me-headaches src/plugins
```

and

```
// main.js
import PackageGivingMeHeadaches from "~/plugins/package-giving-me-headaches"
```

Depending on the package, you may need to target a specific entry point :

```
// main.js
import PackageGivingMeHeadaches from "~/plugins/package-giving-me-headaches/src"
```

You know you need to do that when Gridsome tells you :

```
"export 'default' (imported as 'PackageGivingMeHeadaches') was not found in '~/plugins/package-giving-me-headaches'
```

Edit : Yes, i know its not ideal and ugly, but i don't have time to fight for it.

Comment: Thanks [@HPDL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11790609/hpdl) for taking the time to propose a solution. I wouldn't downvote it but I also don't think it's an ideal solution.