# Gridsome build failing with TypeError

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typeerror, gridsome, vue-meta

I'm encountering some trouble running Gridsome build on a starter project template.  The site runs on `localhost` with no problem. I tried `npm install gridsome@latest` to update or install any missing packages.

Gridsome build gives me the following error:

```
    Could not generate HTML for "/work/":
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'console' of null
      at Object. (C:\Users\Micah\Desktop\my-gridsome-site\node_modules\vue-meta\dist\vue-meta.common.js:103:23)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
      at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
      at C:\Users\Micah\Desktop\my-gridsome-site\node_modules\vue-server-renderer\build.prod.js:1:77671
      at Object. (webpack:/external "vue-meta":1:0)
```

The code at `vue-meta.common.js:103:23` reads `var console = _global.console || {};` as shown below:

```
var hasGlobalWindow = hasGlobalWindowFn();

var _global = hasGlobalWindow ? window : global;

var console = _global.console || {};
function warn(str) {
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  if (!console || !console.warn) {
    return;
  }

  console.warn(str);
}
var showWarningNotSupported = function showWarningNotSupported() {
  return warn('This vue app/component has no vue-meta configuration');
};
```

**Steps to reproduce**

Run gridsome build from command line.

**Environment**

```
System:
OS: Windows 10
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz
Binaries:
Node: 10.16.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
npm: 6.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
Browsers:
Edge: 44.18362.449.0
npmPackages:
gridsome: ^0.7.11 => 0.7.11
gridsome-plugin-tailwindcss: ^2.2.26 => 2.2.26
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm getting this error as well on `gridsome build`. I am using tailwindcss as well.

Comment: I remade the project and added packages one by one.  I believe mine was failing on vue-parallax-js

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is only in build because of [lack of SSR](https://gridsome.org/docs/assets-scripts/#without-ssr-support) (server side rendering) of your component. There is no window in build mode. Try to wrap your component inside vue's `<template>` tag with `<ClientOnly>` tag like this:

```js
<template>
  <ClientOnly>
    <my-component />
  </ClientOnly>
</template>
```